# How do pass in DOCKER_OPTS into docker image running from Docker for Mac?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

My root problem is that I need to support a local docker registry, self-signed certs and whatnot, and after upgrading to Docker for Mac, I haven't quite been able to figure out how to pass in options, or persist options, in the docker/alpine image running via the new and shiny xhyve that got installed with Docker for Mac.

I do have the functional piece of my problem solved, but it's very manual:

1. `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty`
2. log in as root
3. `vi /etc/init.d/docker`
4. Append `--insecure-registry foo.local.machine:5000` to `DOCKER_OPTS`; write file; quit `vi`.
5. `/etc/init.d/docker restart`

Now, if from the perspective of the main OS / OSX, Docker is restarted -- like a simple reboot of the computer -- of course this change and option is lost, and I have to go through this process again.

So, what can I do to automate this?

- Am I missing where DOCKER_OPTS may be set? The `/etc/init.d/docker` file, internally, doesn't overwrite the env var, it appends to it, so this seems like it should be possible.
- Am I missing where files may be persisted in the new docker image? I admit I'm not as familiar with it than the older image that I believe was boot2docker based, where I could have a persisted volume attached, and an entry point where to start these modifications.

Thank you for any help, assistance, and inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Docker preferences (you can find icon on main panel)
2. Advanced -> Insecure docker registry

[Advanced settings pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR4Li.png)

Comment: **Thank you** for pointing this out to me! I can't believe I missed this!